# All planets and stars flat, how to bring day and night effect?

Tags: astronomy

In a scenario in which all heavenly bodies are flat including earth. How to bring the effect of day and night effect like now i.e when day in japan and night in USA .

Considering nobody can live below the flat surface. What motion does flat planets have to move around a flat Sun to get this effect or is it impossible ?

Fundamental gravitational laws should be obeyed for above.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Which is one reason we know the Earth isn't flat.

Comment: Obeying fundamental gravitational laws? Your flat planets collapse into spheres, becoming molten in the process. Your flat stars collapse into spheres, and since there was enough material for them to start fusing while in a flat disc those spheres collapse further into black holes. Day and night are now meaningless.

Comment: What....happened for the planets and stars to become flat?

Comment: @maxisalamone , flat earth society were blessed by god !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a small sun placed above the middle of the planet disk, with its disk at right angles to the planet. One side is dark and one side bright, and it slowly rotates, exposing its bright side to different halves of the planet disk as it rotates. Half the planet is in sunlight, the other half in darkness, with light dimming near the terminator (light/darkness boundary) because the sun disk is seen at an angle.

The light gets dimmer as you move close to the center 'pole' of the planet because you always view the sun at an angle, and directly below the disk is eternal darkness since the sun disk is always edge on.

The planet disk also rotates slowly, but the sun is in geostationary orbit, so it always stays above the same spot. The underside of the planet is in perpetual darkness.

Comment: Rotates while remaining perpendicular? Like a coin being spun on a table? So that day and night are almost a searchlight sweeping around the disc of the earth?

Comment: @Jontia: Exactly - but with the coin floating above the table.